# Linking ID from one table to data in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have an assignment where I am to create two tables within a database. The tables looks like this;

ContactPerson (ID, Forename, Surname, Email, PhoneNumber)
Company (ID, CompanyName)

Now my problem is that I have to link a ContactPerson to a specific company, but I can't have them in the same table.

I understand that I can use the join statement to show both tables in one query but I need the database to know which person is linked to which company when I implement this databse into my asp.net project.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did say "specific" company so I'm assuming you have one company per person.

Put a column in the user table called CompanyID...

```
ALTER TABLE ContactPerson
ADD CompanyID int
```

(assuming your ids are ints)
 and then create the following foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].ContactPerson
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactPerson_Company] 
    FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID)
    REFERENCES Company (ID)
```

Shark is correct if you want a many to many relationship.

To get all people in a company:

SELECT
    *
FROM
   ContactPerson
WHERE
   CompanyID = x

You don't HAVE to apply the foreign key constraint, but if you don't, you can accidentally put invalid data in. All a "Constraint" does is enforce a rule for you, in other words "making sure sql knows which people are in which company" as your question suggests you need to do.

The above query would work without the Foreign key constraint, but then your database doesn't "know" about the relationship.

..and if I try and insert a person with a companyid that doesn't exist, SQL will throw an error (this is a good thing).

Comment: Yes every person should be linked to one company. Every company however, can have several persons linked to it.

How do keys work? I have never worked with keys before.

Comment: A foreign key is just a way to tell sql a column in one table links to a column in another table. Foreign keys is what I'd imagine your assignment is about.

Comment: I keep getting an error (msg 1776) when I try to create the key. And when I try to create a primary key I get an error saying that it found a duplicate key. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but either you've created a primary key on another column in the table or you've not set a primary key on the company table ID column first? I'd have to see the schema to be sure, but it's bound to be something simple.

Comment: Have you already inserted data into the tables? Select all on both tables and check that you don't have duplicate ID values for either as well.

Comment: I just did what you told me to do, but I got that error and tried to fix it by creating a primary key. I have deleted both tables now though and created two new ones so everything is back to default now. Adding the FK key is still not working though, so what do I need to do?

Comment: You will need to script the tables including extended properties for me to be able to tell what's wrong. I can't tell without seeing what te current schema is.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a one-to-many relationship, I would typically put that data into the `ContactPerson` table.  But because you explicitly say you cannot, then just create a join table:

```
create table ContactPersonCompany
(
    ContactPersonID int not null foreign key references ContactPerson(ID),
    CompanyID int not null foreign key references Company(ID)
)
```

Now you have a relationship between `ContactPerson` and `Company`.

*Example: select all people from a particular company*

```
select
    cp.Surname,
    cp.Forename
from ContactPerson cp
inner join ContactPersonCompany cpc
on cp.ID = cpc.ContactPersonID
inner join Company c
on cpc.CompanyID = c.ID
where c.CompanyName = 'Some Company'
```