# Linking ID in a table to data in another table - but in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been looking at foreign keys and things because I have an assignment coming up so I'm trying to get a grasp on everything so I'm ready. I was looking at [Linking ID from one table to data in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720011/linking-id-from-one-table-to-data-in-another-table) and the answer mentions a way to do it in a many-to-many relationship but I can't see it anywhere, so I'd like to know how to do this.

When looking at the linked question, an example I'd like would be many `ContactPerson` could work for many `Company`.

I'm not sure if asking a question in this format is correct, but I thought it easier to link to the existing question rather than rewriting it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a many-to-many relationship, which consists of 3 tables:

1. Company
2. ContactPerson
3. Company2ContactPerson

Example here:
http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer, but that's a terrible table name (personally, I'm a little leery of using 'To' as a relationship specifier, much less substituting the numeric value).  Additionally, to protect from link-rot, perhaps you could show the minimum expected fields for the cross-reference table?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, there's an in-depth explanation and examples which can be found here: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx